# Why are caterpillar plots used so much in mixed effects models?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

I see that a lot of people using caterpillar plots to describe the results of mixed effects models. Why do people use this plot so much and what other plots to people use to talk about mixed models? Also, any references would be welcomed.

Update: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847936/in-r-plotting-random-effects-from-lmer-lme4-package-using-qqmath-or-dotplot) is a link to how to plot caterpillar plots in R.

[image]

Comment: What's a caterpillar plot?  Including a picture would be useful.

Comment: Well the title of the linked post is, "How to make it fancy". So I guess people like the fancy-ness of it.